# replacing a string contained withing two strings with an incremental counter in bash

Tags: text, awk, sed

I am trying to change a file looking like this :

```
>sample_A#Dakota
text
text
text
>text_2#Idao
text
text
text
>junk_1#Alabama
text
text
text
>example_4#Dakota
text
text
text
>example5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

to a file looking like this :

```
>model_1#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_2#Idao
text
text
text
>model_3#Alabama
text
text
text
>model_4#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

So, I need to find the text between > and #, and replace it with "model" followed by an incremental number. I have found some answers only for doing these thing separately, but I haven't been able to combine them. I would want to use bash, with a one-line answer like a sed or an awk. 
I have tried this :

```
awk 'BEGIN { cntr = 0 } />/,/#/ { cntr++ ; print "model", cntr } !/>/,/#/ { print $0 }' infile
```

but I got this :

```
model 1
text
text
text
model 2
>text_2#Idao
text
text
text
model 3
>junk_1#Alabama
text
text
text
model 4
>example_4#Dakota
text
text
text
model 5
>example5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

Thanks in advance, 
T

Comment: `/regexp1/,/regexp2/` syntax is for defining group of lines matching those regexp, not for single line match.. should be `/>.*#/` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^>.*#/{sub(/^>[^#]+/, ">model_" ++c)} 1' ip.txt
>model_1#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_2#Idao
text
text
text
>model_3#Alabama
text
text
text
>model_4#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

- `/^>.*#/` if line starts with `>` and has `#` in the line
- `sub` function helps to search and replace first match
- `/^>[^#]+/` match characters from start of line from `>` until just before `#` character
- `">model_" ++c` replacement string

  - `c` will be zero at the start (since this is numerical context), `++c` will give the value after incrementing, so first time we get `1`, next time `2` and so on

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'sub(/^>[^#]+/,""){$0=">model1_" (++cnt) $0} 1' file
>model1_1#Dakota
text
text
text
>model1_2#Idao
text
text
text
>model1_3#Alabama
text
text
text
>model1_4#Dakota
text
text
text
>model1_5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk 'match($0,/>.*#/){print ">model_"++count"#" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);next} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^>/{$0=">model_" ++c "#" $3}1' FS='[>#]' file
```

I used `>` and `#` as field separators.

Output:

```
>model_1#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_2#Idao
text
text
text
>model_3#Alabama
text
text
text
>model_4#Dakota
text
text
text
>model_5#Honduras
text
text
text
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):

```
sed -E '/^>.*#/{x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x;G;s/^[^#]*(.*)\n(.*)/echo "model_\2\1"/e}' file
```

For lines that begin `>` and contain `#`, increment a counter in the hold space (HS), append the HS to the current line and re-arrange into the desired format.